# How to update the file related to a `fileInput` variable in R Shiny without user interaction?

Tags: r, file, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm working on an app in R where the users need to choose a file from their computer, with a *RShiny* `fileInput` button. I want to modify this, so that the associated variable can be assigned (i.e. a file can be loaded) automatically by the programm, without having the user click on the button and choose the file.

The problem I'm facing is that a `fileInput` has 4 fields, amongst which I only can know 3. For instance, when I load the file `hello.csv` in the variable `inFile` through the normal procedure, here is what I get :

```
inFile$name = hello.csv
inFile$size = 8320
inFile$type = text/csv
inFile$datapath = C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpkh8Zcb/7d5f0ff0111d440c7a66b656/0
```

Though I could have guessed the second and the third one knowing the file, I have no idea how the `datapath` field is assigned...

I've tried to declare `inFile` as a `NULL` global variable, then to assign one by one the different fields, but I'm stuck with this last one. Is there an other way to do, like a function that mimics the behaviour of a user who clicks on the file input button and choose a specified file ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the actual goal you're trying to achieve? There might be an easier way to do what you're trying to do. As for the data path, I'm not entirely sure how it's assigned either, but I believe it's a security thing. Try tinkering with `tempfile()` and see how the output compares to `inFile$datapath`. That might get you what you need.

Comment: The function `tempfile()` provides me a file name located in my `AppData\Local\Temp` directory (so it is indeed similar to the `datapath` field I'm looking for), but I doesn't help me loading the file, which is what I aim at.

Comment: If all you're looking to do is load the file, then you don't need to use `fileInput` from Shiny. Given that `fileInput` just collects the information about a file, which in turn lets you load a file, you can just load whatever file you want via `read.csv`, `read.table`, etc. You can then make an `observeEvent(input$inFile, {...})` function that listens for when someone loads a new file and processes that information. See my (incomplete) answer below for what this might look like.

Comment: I thought about that, but the code I'm working with uses that `fileInput` very often, that's why I wanted to re-create the process that the users make when they load the file : I could then juste leave the rest of the code alone

Comment: Can you give an example of how you might use the information from `fileInput` of the initially loaded file?

Comment: I've got lines like : `inFile <- input$fileMeasurement` then `dataFilePeriod <- read.csv( inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)`
I'll test your solution and check the result

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're looking for with this question. If the problem is that you have `input$inFile$datapath` sprinkled through your code and you don't to change it, then I'm not sure there's much you can do. Take a look at my updated answer below and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm about to test it right away ! I would have proceed in some other way, but the code isn't mine and the original developer did put quite a mess in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I figured it out :

---

I edited the original code, so that all the `read.csv(...)` are replaced with calls to a `data.frame` global variable. I  also added a small button that you need to click on before you continue. This button saves what you just loaded in the Database (if you chose a file with the `fileInput`) and assigns the right values to the global variables that will be needed for the following operations. If you chose no file at all, it will directly assign the variables from the data found in the Database.

So I did not find a proper solution to the problem, but this is a workaround that will do the job in my case.

---

@brittenb I couldn't get your *reactive* solution to work as I wanted to, that's why I ended up doing this another way. Thanks for having taken the time to think about it though.

I'm still open to suggestions on how to update the file in a `fileInput` without user interaction.

Answer (score 5):

If all you're looking to do is load a file initially, you don't have to rely on Shiny functions to do that. You can just rely on R functions. Set up your app like this:

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fileInput("inFile", label="Choose a file", multiple=F)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues()

  dat <- reactive({
    if (is.null(inFile$datapath)) {
      dat <- read.csv("path/to/your.csv")
      values$file_name = "your.csv"
      values$file_type = "csv"
      values$file_size = file.size("path/to/your.csv")
      values$file_path = "path/to/your.csv"
    } else {
      dat <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
      values$file_name = inFile$name
      values$file_size = inFile$size
      values$file_type = inFile$type
      values$file_path = inFile$datapath
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

In the above code, the Shiny app will start and see that `inFile$datapath` is `NULL` and will load a predefined file of your choosing. It won't run again until `inFile` changes, at which point it will load the file that the user pointed to.

Hope that helps.

### Update

I changed the code above to use `reactiveValues` to store the pieces of information that need to be used throughout the app. If you just set those and then do a find/replace for `input$inFile$datapath` and replace it `values$file_path`, your code should work just fine.

Comment: OK so I tested it, and this will at least help me clean the code, with this `reactive` variable that I can manipulate (thaks for that). However, this still does not answer my first problem : I would like to be able to replicate what happens when a user uses a `fileInput`, clicks on a button and chooses the file, but with no user interaction. What I truly need is like an `updateFileInput` function (to call it whenever I want), which does not exist in R... If there is no way to workaround I'll modify the original code but I don't like this perspective.

Comment: What is the primary objective of being able to do that? The only thing `fileInput` does is collect information about a file. if the user isn't specifying what file for which Shiny should memorize the data, then why feign the function?

Comment: In short, the `fileInput` is associated to a variable, which has several fields (`name`, `datapath`, etc.). The fields are initialized when the user chooses the file, right ? The thing is, the original code makes many calls (`read.csv` for instance) to this variable. But with the functionality I'm developing (trying to implement a Database Saving possibility), the user does not choose the file _via_ the `fileInput` as before; it is the app that fetches it automatically. Therefore I would like to make the app choose the file like a user would, and I believe the shortest way is this.

Comment: Again, `read.csv` is just going to read from `input$inFile$datapath`, so why not just find/replace that with `values$ file_path` given what you want to do?  Otherwise, use `file.copy` to copy it to a `tempfile()` and take note of the file path.

Comment: Because the path in my datapath is unknown to me, since it is something of the form `C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpKEqogr/5d8fea7c16d280244869b13d/0` (I printed it from the `inFile` variable)

Comment: Right, but that's only true when you load a file with `fileInput`. If you load it youself, it will be "C:/Users/MyName/Folder/file.ext", which, by definition,  has to be known to you since you're loading the file. Either way, you just assign that value to `values$file_path` and use that instead of `input$inFile$datapath`.